# How can i pass Ionic MultiDex Error when android build?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, android-multidex, lottie

I added LottieSplashScreen to my Project but i can't build. This error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
```

Comment: Need More Information. Share your Ionic, Cordova and Plugins details.

Comment: I fixed it. I deleted the platform first, then built it